# I cant open scrapy shell at anaconda shell

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I was trying to start the `scrapy shell` on anaconda

But this Error occured multiple times;

`[scrapy.core.downloader.handlers] ERROR: Loading "scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http.HTTPDownloadHandler" for scheme "http" Traceback (most recent call last): ........ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrs'`

I tried to reinstall scrapy but it still doesnt work
Can someone please help me :)

Comment: Try manually installing `attrs` with pip and run the command again.